# Why negative image is used in preprocessing?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, ocr, image-recognition

I've observed that for many preprocessing operations (I mean mainly preprocessing for OCR) usually negative image is used?

For example:
http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/10/opencv-rotation-deskewing/
http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/

I've found it also when objects are found using kNN algorithm.

Why inverted images are used? Is that only to show it is just preprocessing step? Are there any advantages during using inverted images?

Comment: The image is converted to a binary mask where 0 = false = no foreground and >0 = true = foreground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is more or less given the [second example you linked](http://felix.abecassis.me/2011/09/opencv-detect-skew-angle/):

> In image processing, objects are white and the background is black,
>   we have the opposite, we need to invert the colors of our image

By convention most image processing detection algorithms assume what's supposed to be detected is white and the background is black. However most text in the real world is black text on white background, like for example a page of a book, so many real world images will need to be inverted to match the assumptions of the image detection algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

No, there are strictly no advantages in working with inverted images. Linear filtering and edge detection are strictly insensitive to contrast reversal. Morphological filters are always defined in dual pairs (both polarities). Binarization and blob analysis are also contrast independent. (Assuming of course that you make the right association of background/foreground and black/white.) There is a complete symmetry.

The reason why some text is shown white on black is often purely practical: you can see the limits of the region of interest ! (Other reason can be that the library on hand is just lacking the option of a white background.)

Answer (score 1):

Black and white images more convenient than colored images while processing.

Answer (score 1):

After 19 years in OCR and document processing industry, this is the first time I hear this.  It may be tool-specific, but it is definitely not a widely acceptable practice.  All image pre-processing happens on normal black on white images in commercial OCR packages we use, representative of a real world documents.  Inversion can be tried in low contrast situations, but it is infrequent.

I still learn something new every day.  Are there any other references to this method being frequently used?